# Multiple tables using dataReader

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to load data into text field from two table in mysql database, but it won't load

Here is my code

```vb
Private Sub LoadData()
        connString = "Server=Localhost;Database=smart_parking;User Id=root;password="
        conn = New MySqlConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
        sql = "select a.*, k.* from a anggota, k kendaraan where a.id_card = '" + ComboId.Text + "'"
        Dim SqlCommand As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        reader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader
        Try
            reader.Read()
            TxtKartu.Text = reader.GetString(0)
            TxtId.Text = reader.GetString(1)
            TxtNama.Text = reader.GetString(2)
            TxtAlamat.Text = reader.GetString(3)
            TxtUmur.Text = reader.GetString(4)
            TxtPekerjaan.Text = reader.GetString(5)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex)
        End Try
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

it didn't say anything, just can't load any data to the text field. But if I use only one table, it worked perfectly.
Anyone know what the problem is ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you have a correct syntax for your select statement. I guess what you need is a [join query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Thank you @chinz, work like magic. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @chinz can i ask again ? the inner join works perfect. but when i change the comboid value, it just value of the first table that only changed, the second table wasn't. here is my query "select * from anggota inner join kendaraan on anggota.id_card = '" + ComboId.Text + "'"

Comment: This will be vulnerable to sql injection.